# List of arrays: find item by array key, create or update as appropriate

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have lists of arrays like this:

```
var a = [
   {  month: 'January', count: 3 },
   {  month: 'February', count: 5 }, 
   {  month: 'March', count: 4 }
];
var b = [
   {  month: 'January', count: 4 },
   {  month: 'February', count: 5 }, 
   {  month: 'March', count: 1 }
];
```

And I want to create a "total" list, using Underscore, that looks like this:

```
var totals = [
   {  month: 'January', count: 7 },
   {  month: 'February', count: 10 }, 
   {  month: 'March', count: 5 }
];
```

I don't know in advance what the values of "month" will be, so I need to allow for this.

This is as far as I've got, but it's not very elegant. Is there a nicer way?

```
var totals = [];
_.each([a, b], function(d) { 
   _.each(items, function(e) { 
    var matchingItem = _.filter(totals, function(item, i) {
      return (item.month === e.month);
    });
    if (matchingItem) {
       var i = totals.indexOf(matchingItem);
       totals[i].count += e.count;
    } else { 
       var newItem = e;
       totals.push(e);
    }

   });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Underscore functions, you may do it like this, using a temporary object:

```
var total = [];
var tmp = {};

_.each(_.flatten([a,b]), function (obj) {
    tmp[obj.month] = tmp[obj.month] ? tmp[obj.month] + obj.count : obj.count;
});
_.each(tmp, function (c,m) {
    total.push({month: m, count: c});
});
```

See code there : http://jsfiddle.net/8cxQB/

Answer (score 2):

This solution concatenates all the arrays, groups them by month and then spits out the totals:

```
var months = a.concat(b);

var totals = _.map( _.groupBy(months, 'month'), function(values, month){
    return {
        month: month,
        count: _.reduce(values, function(memo,value){
            return memo + value.count
        }, 0)
    }
});
```

If there are more data arrays then the months array could be built like so:

```
var months = a.concat(b, c, d); // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var totals = {};

a.concat(b).forEach(function(el) {
  if(totals[el.month])
    totals[el.month].count = totals[el.month].count + el.count;
  else
    totals[el.month] = el;
})

console.log(totals);
```

Comment: I get `{ undefined: NaN }`

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to add another plugin, linq.js would be your best bet
http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

EDIT:

```
var a = [
   {  month: 'January', count: 3 },
   {  month: 'February', count: 5 }, 
   {  month: 'March', count: 4 }
];
var b = [
   {  month: 'January', count: 4 },
   {  month: 'February', count: 5 }, 
   {  month: 'March', count: 1 }
];

var queryResult = Enumerable.From(a).Union(b)
.GroupBy("$.month", "", function (key, g) { var result = { month: key, count: g.Sum("$.count") }; return result;})
.ToArray();

console.log(queryResult);
```

Comment: Linq instead of Underscore might be a solution, but then at least provide the code to solve the OP's problem instead of a random sample.

Comment: Sorry about that, thought the first example was straightforward enough. I posted a real answer using linq.js now. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Why not have done an object like this

```
var counts =  {
   'January': 3,
   'February': 5 , 
   'March': 4
}
```

and then you can acces it with `counts.January` directly and modify it or within a loop with `counts[month_name] = ...`

hope that help

Comment: That would undoubtedly be better, but unfortunately that's not the nature of the data I'm dealing with - it's returned from an API and I don't control the structure...

Answer (score 0):

Although not very elegant, this solution is one-lineish and doesn't use third party libs.

```js
Array.from([...a, ...b].reduce((p, c) => p.set(c.month, {month: c.month, count: (p.get(c.month)?.count ?? 0) + c.count}), new Map())).map(x => x[1])

// readable version
Array.from([...a, ...b]
  .reduce((previous, current) => {
    const count = (previous.get(current.month) ?? 0) + current.count
    return previous.set(current.month, { month: current.month, count })
  }, new Map()))
  .map(x => x[1])
```